# React query and mixed bulk / specific queries

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tanstackreact-query

In a large project, we have both a bulk and a specific "details" query like:

```
dataBulk_Get(subjectIds: string[]): DataDto[]
```

and

```
dataSingle_Get(subjectId: string): DataDto
```

The most simple solution would to have two queries, with two distinct query keys, right?

So

```
const bulkData = useQuery({queryKey: ['data', 'bulk', {subjectIds[]}], queryFn: () =>....);
```

and

```
const singleData = useQuery({queryKey: ['data', 'single', {subjectId}], queryFn: () =>....);
```

But it seems inefficient that I might get to load the same data twice (or more), I might have loaded bulk first, and then want a single entry after that (normally would be fetched with `dataSingle`). So, I first get `bulkData` for id's `5`, `11`, and `20`, and just after that I request data for `id` `11`.

Another example: I might have one page where I want `subjectIds` `1`, `5`, `10` and `15`, while next page would be `5`, `7`, `10` and `20`, so I end up loading data for `subjectId` `5` and `10` twice in two different `queryKeys`, as `{1, 5, 10, 15} !== {5, 7, 10, 20}`

Can we destructure `queryKeys` inside a `queryFn`, and change it to use a different `queryKey`? (load bulk data, and then split the data up by `subjectId` when storing)

Comment: Perhaps check out this example of batching on React Query's docs site; I think it aligns with the use case you're describing: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/community/batching-requests-using-bathshit

Comment: Yup, forgot about this SO question. But "batshit" is the way forward, only caveat is that you should not request more than roughly 20000 entries in one useQueries or it will choke on the data and freeze the browser

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using `useQuery`'s option `initialData`. It's a way of telling useQuery that you already have valid data and it can skip the initial fetch.

[getQueriesData](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientgetqueriesdata)() is a function that returns cached data of multiple queries. Note that it returns an array of tuples.

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()

const previousDataset = queryClient
  .getQueriesData(['data', 'bulk'])
  ?.find(([key, data])=> 
    data.findIndex(({id}) => id === subjectId) > -1
  );

const singleData = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['data', 'single', {subjectId}],
  queryFn: () =>....,
  initialData: previousDataset && previousDataset[1].find(({id}) => id === subjectId),
  initialDataUpdatedAt: () =>
      previousDataset && queryClient.getQueryState(previousDataset[0])?.dataUpdatedAt,
);
```

You could clean up my code to be a little DRYer but it's enough to illustrate the point.

[More details](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/placeholder-and-initial-data-in-react-query) on setting initial data.

Answer (score 0):

React Query has a [method](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-react-query-3#query-data-selectors) called `select` which will allow you to filter the data, and cache only what you want:

```js
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'

function User() {
  const { data } = useQuery(['user'], fetchUser, {
    select: user => user.username,
  })
  return <div>Username: {data}</div>
}
```

So if I understand your question correctly, you can do something like:

```js
useQuery({
   queryKey: ['data', 'single', subjectId], 
   queryFn: () => getSubjects(), 
   select: data => data.filter(id => subjectId),
});
```

You could also potentially read the bulk data using the [queryClient](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientgetquerydata) and then filter to the `subjectId` you need.

```js
const data = queryClient.getQueryData(queryKey)
const subject = data.filter(id => subjectId)
```

**Edit as per comment:**

I tried to illustrate how you can reuse cached data, using the queries you already have. RQ allows you to consume data through multiple methods, so a pattern I prefer is this. A working [replit for you here](https://replit.com/@potgied/MistyroseExternalSets#src/App.tsx).

```js
function Feed() {
  const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useQuery(
    {
      queryKey: ['feed'],
      queryFn: getFeed
    }
  )

  if(isError) console.log(error)

  return isLoading ?
    <div>loading</div> :
    <div><pre>{JSON.stringify(data?.slice(0, 2), null, 2)} + {data.length - 2} more...</pre></div>
}

function CoinByIdfromQuery({pair}: {pair: string}) {
    const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useQuery(
    {
      queryKey: ['feed', { pair }],
      queryFn: getFeed,
      select: coins => coins.filter(coin => coin.pair === pair)
    }
  )

  if(isError) console.log(error)
  
  return isLoading ?
    <div>loading</div> :
    <div><pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre></div>
}

function CoinBySelectfromQuery({pair}: {pair: string}) {
    const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useQuery(
    {
      queryKey: ['feed'],
      queryFn: getFeed,
      select: coins => coins.filter(coin => coin.pair === pair)
    }
  )

  if(isError) console.log(error)
  
  return isLoading ?
    <div>loading</div> :
    <div><pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre></div>
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Feed />
      <CoinByIdfromQuery pair="BTCUSD" />
      <CoinBySelectfromQuery pair="BTCUSD" />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}
```

1. `Feed` will make the initial query and cache all the data from that API for you. (First API call) Depending on how you configure your `cacheTime` and `stateTime` this query will not make another API call until either condition is met.
2. Although `CoinByIdfromQuery` seems similar, the `queryKey` is not the same as in `Feed`, so it will make another API call, and cache that specific key/data for you. The call is the same, the function is the same, the only difference is the `queryKey`
3. `CoinBySelectfromQuery` will NOT make another call. The `queryKey` is the same as in `Feed`, so if your `cacheTime` and `stateTime` have not been met, it will not make another trip to the API. The downside here is, that your `queryClient.getQueryData(['feed'])` now only contains that single key, so your `Feed` will not display all data once your user navigates back to it.
4. `CoinByIdfromCache` (in the replit) shows you how to pull data from the cache without a query. Downsides are that you need to manage loading and error states yourself, AND (most importantly) the cache might not exist at that time, so your user might find empty states.

So, my personal advice would be, don't worry about doing one more call to the API. If the data differs between calls, then it's absolutely needed to keep your cache in tact. You can hack your way through it, but the key here is "hack".

If you go the `Feed` then `CoinByIdfromQuery` route, then for the feed and each `pair` you will have a cache.

1. `Feed` - 1 call
2. User navigates to "BTCUSD" screen (as example) - 1 call
3. User navigates back to `Feed` - no call, cache
4. User navigates to "DOGEETH" screen - 1 call
5. User navigates back to `Feed` - no call, cache
6. User navigates to "BTCUSD" screen again - no call, cache
7. etc. (assuming your `cacheTime` and `stateTime` have not been met)

Comment: But if I have a bulk query, and specify the `subjectIds[]` in the query key, then it would cache data for that specific set of subjectIds. Then if I later request a subset of the same subjectIds, I will query the backend again, as the list of subjectIds[] has changed, and so has the query key.

Comment: Also it's not a filtering issue per se. It's more that I want to load a set of data specified by id's from the backend using one query. And I do not wish to fetch the same data twice if it's not necessary.

We could use the method for fetching a single item, but then we might swamp the backend with queries when we want to get the details for 1000 items.

Backend is using bounded contexts, so we can not make a single query that returns all the needed data for our table views.. As we might get a bunch of ids from module A, which needs to be merged with data from module B.

Comment: @TBowmo - I added a more detailed example. Please let me know if you have more questions. In short, I think you will need to make individual calls, but you can cache each of those, so the next visit will not make additional calls.

Answer (score -2):

Found a way with the library yornaath/batshit, https://github.com/yornaath/batshit

Something like the below should do it

```js
import {create, keyResolver} from '@yornaath/batshit'
import {useQuery, useQueries} from '@tanstack/react-query'

const users = create({
    fetcher: async (ids: number[]) => {
        return client.users.where({
            userId_in: ids,
        })
    },
    resolver: keyResolver('id'),
})

function query(id: number) {
    return {
        queryKey: ['users', id],
        queryFn: () => users.fetch(id),
    }
}

function useUser(id: number) {
    return useQuery(query(id))
}

function useUsers(ids: number[]) {
    return useQueries({
        queries: ids.map(query),
        combine: (results) => results.map((result) => result.data),
    })
}
```

The above batches the queries into a single query with an array of userids.

One caveat to this is however that tanstack query has issues if you are trying to load more than 20-25k entries (ref https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/6305), so if you load *really* large datasets you'll have to take another approach.